# How to implement a SaveAs Dialog in a JfreeChart SaveAsPNG method

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jfreechart, rcp

Please, I need your help. Could you tell me how to implement a SWT SaveAs Dialog in the next code? I need that user can choose where he wants to save the chart. Thanks!

```
 try {
                File file = new File("mychart.png");
                float calidad = 1;

                ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(file, calidad, chart, 800, 600);
                MessageDialog.openInformation(shell, "Save Chart", "The file has been saved");

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                MessageDialog.openInformation(shell, "Save Chart", "Error saving file. Please try again...");
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the SWT `FileDialog` - something like:

```
Shell shell = ... current shell

FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(shell, SWT.SAVE);

fileDialog.setFilterExtensions(new String [] {"*.png", "*.*"});

fileDialog.setFilterPath(.... any default path you want ....);

String filePath = fileDialog.open();

// TODO check for null 'filePath' - user canceled the save

File file = new File(filePath);

ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file, calidad, chart, 800, 600);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Greg! You are a genius! Regards!